# Does taking the negative of the anti-hermitian matrix A turn it into Hermitian or does it stay anti-Hermitian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Attempted solution:
Say that we have matrix A, that is anti-hermitian. 
$$A= - A^{\dagger}$$
Taking the negative: 
$$-A= - (-A)^{\dagger}$$
$$-A= A^{\dagger}$$
which shows that it's still anti-Hermitian. So multiplying a negative doesn't effect the state of the matrix A being anti-Hermitian. Does my argument check out?

Comment: Yes and in general, if $A$ is skew-Hermitian, $cA$ will also be skew-Hermitian for any *real* scalar $c$.

Comment: @EPIC Tube HD: Did you finish this problem?

Comment: @Axion004 yes I did

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your argument is correct. The negative of an antihermitian matrix $A$ remains antihermitian. For an example, observe that if

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
-i & 2+i\\
-2+i & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

then $A$ is anti-Hermetian since

$$-A =
  \begin{bmatrix} i & -2 - i \\ 2 - i & 0 \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{-i}    & \overline{-2 + i} \\
    \overline{2 + i} & \overline{0}
  \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{-i}     & \overline{2 + i} \\
    \overline{-2 + i} &     \overline{0}
  \end{bmatrix}^\mathsf{T} =
  A^\mathsf{H}
$$

and writing

$$-A=
\begin{bmatrix}
i & -2-i\\
2-i & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

would produce

$$-(-A) = A=
  \begin{bmatrix} -i & 2 + i \\ -2 + i & 0 \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{i}    & \overline{2 - i} \\
    \overline{-2 - i} & \overline{0}
  \end{bmatrix} =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \overline{i}     & \overline{-2 - i} \\
    \overline{2 - i} &     \overline{0}
  \end{bmatrix}^\mathsf{T} =
  -A^\mathsf{H}
$$